# How to open and check whether Play Protect is enabled or disabled

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, android-settings, google-settings

```
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
```

Using below code, I can able to open the **Google Settings** page.

```
private static final String GOOGLE_SETTINGS_COMPONENT = "com.google.android.gms";
private static final String GOOGLE_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY = ".app.settings.GoogleSettingsActivity";
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(GOOGLE_SETTINGS_COMPONENT,GOOGLE_SETTINGS_COMPONENT + GOOGLE_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY);
try {
      startActivity(i);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

1. Is it possible to directly open the **Google Settings** --> **Security** --> **Google Play Protect** page.
2. How to check whether the **Scan device for security threats** option is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible to directly open the Google Settings --> Security -->
>   Google Play Protect page ?

You can use the `com.google.android.gms.security.settings.VerifyAppsSettingsActivity` intent to launch play protect screen directly as below.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.google.android.gms", "com.google.android.gms.security.settings.VerifyAppsSettingsActivity"))
startActivity(intent)
```

[Here](https://www.reverse.it/sample/01467fc1deba0800ab8f03e330743f5de1b12a01b154dbbb916a42975c1420f1?environmentId=200) is the meta data of playstore APK you can see all available activities out there.

> 2) How to check whether the Scan device for security threats option is
>   enabled or disabled?

Developers can get similar security insights into the installed apps landscape on user devices from the SafetyNet [Verify Apps API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/verify-apps.html). This new suite of APIs lets developers determine whether a user's device is protected by Google Play Protect, encourage users not already using Google Play Protect to enable it, and identify any known [potentially harmful apps](https://source.android.com/security/reports/Google_Android_Security_PHA_classifications.pdf) (PHAs) that are installed on the device.

These APIs are especially useful for developers of apps that may be impacted by installed PHAs on the same device as their app. Determining that Google Play Protect is enabled with [`isVerifyAppsEnabled()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient.html#isVerifyAppsEnabled()) gives developers additional assurance that a device is more likely to be clean. If a device doesn't have Google Play Protect enabled, developers can request that the user enable Google Play Protect with [`enableVerifyApps()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient.html#enableVerifyApps()). With Google Play Protect enabled, developers can use the [`listHarmfulApps()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient.html#listHarmfulApps()) method to determine whether there are any potentially harmful apps installed on a user's device. This easy-to-use suite of features does not require API keys and requesting quota.

Compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.6.0` and use the below code.

> Determine whether app verification is enabled

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this)
    .isVerifyAppsEnabled()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<VerifyAppsUserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<VerifyAppsUserResponse> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                VerifyAppsUserResponse result = task.getResult();
                if (result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()) {
                    Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "The Verify Apps feature is enabled.");
                } else {
                    Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "The Verify Apps feature is disabled.");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "A general error occurred.");
            }
        }
    });
```

> Request enabling of app verification

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this)
    .enableVerifyApps()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<VerifyAppsUserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<VerifyAppsUserResponse> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                VerifyAppsUserResponse result = task.getResult();
                if (result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()) {
                    Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "The user gave consent " +
                          "to enable the Verify Apps feature.");
                } else {
                    Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "The user didn't give consent " +
                          "to enable the Verify Apps feature.");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "A general error occurred.");
            }
        }
    });
```

*For better protection, developers should use the attestation API along with the new Verify Apps API. Use the [attestation API](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/safetynet-attestation-building-block.html) first to establish that the device has not been modified from a known state. Once the Android system can be trusted, the results from the Verify Apps API can be trusted.*

P.S. Read through the [Additional TOS](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/verify-apps.html#tos) prior using the API

Comment: Thanks Anoop. Is it possible to disable the play protect in a single button? Instead of going inside the page?

Comment: Calling `"com.google.android.gms.security.settings.VerifyAppsSettingsActivity"` seems not working (ActivityNotFoundException).
I did `startActivity(Intent("com.google.android.gms.security.settings.VerifyAppsSettingsActivity"))`
Am I doing wrong? (My Oreo phone has Google Protect menu)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is there any way to disable the Play Protect by using `adb` command line ?

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.google.android.gms", "com.google.android.gms.security.settings.VerifyAppsSettingsActivity" );
try {
    startActivity(i);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).